# Let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be an injective linear map. If $V$ is infinite-dimensional then $W$ must also be infinite-dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be an injective linear map. Show that if $V$ is infinite-dimensional then $W$ must also be infinite-dimensional.

I have an intuition for why this would be true: if $W$ was of finite dimension, you would eventually 'run out' of unique elements in $W$ with which to associate to elements in $V$ through $T$, but I'm having a hard time formalizing this.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Injective linear maps take linearly independent sets to linearly independent sets.